# IntelliJ IDEA: Difference between scratch buffer and files

Tags: intellij-idea

IntelliJ IDEA knows `scratch files` and `scratch buffers`.

This menu show the search action result:
[image]

Both scratch types show up under the `Scratches and Consoles` tree entry:
[image]

What is the difference between scratch file and scratch buffers?

When should I choose one over the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scratch Buffers are limited to 5 max and if you invoke this action again when 5 buffers are already created, you will switch to buffer 1. Scratch Files are unlimited and will not reuse existing files.

Scratch buffers are also Plain Text only, while Scratch Files can have different type that you choose when creating a new scratch file.

Comment: Got it, but I don't see any advantage of using `scratch buffers`. Why should I use them?  
I can create a scratch file with plan text? Could it be, that scratch buffers haven been there before scratch files?

Comment: I guess it's for the cases when you just need a quick text buffer to type in without the need to specify the file type, see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-144140.